# How can I remove the PAGE Title Hyperlink at the top of my page without CSS?

Tags: 2013, hyperlink, editing-menu

I am trying to figure out a way to remove the "Home" Link right above the word "Welcome" on my page. It is part of the actual page structure so I cannot edit out the text.

[image]

I am fairly new to Sharepoint and don't have a designer or know if I can access the actual script to remove it manually. So far I have tried a lot of the click through options but can't find anything that will let me delete or hide it. It is on every page and serves no purpose.

Thanks to anyone that can help out!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do this as Out of the Box. Meanwhile, you can do this via Javascript Without using SharePoint Designer , by adding `Script editor` to your page as the following

- Edit your Page by clicking on the gear icon at the right corner.
- From the above ribbon > click on insert > Web Part.
- At Media and Content > Click on Script Editor.

Add the following Javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function disablelinkPageTitle() {

var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var searchText = "Home"; 
var link;
for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) 
{
 if (aTags[i].textContent == searchText) 
  {
      link = aTags[i];
      link.href="#";
      link.style.cursor = 'default';
      break;
  }
 }
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("disablelinkPageTitle"); 
</script>
```

**OutPut:**

Now You can note the the **cursor is not hand** and when you click on **Home is unclickable**

[image]

Check also the detail steps with image at [Remove Page Title URL at Team Site Page in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/09/22/remove-page-title-url-in-team-site-sharepoint-2013/)

You may also need to Check [Missing EDIT SNIPPET of Script Editor at Team Site Page in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/09/22/missing-edit-snippet-team-site-page-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Add following javascript to your home page and it will hide the Home title along with the exclamation circle next to it. This works in SharePoint 2013:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://spsite.yourcompany.com/SiteAssets/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideHomeTitle() 
{
  //Following code will hide the HOME title on the page
  var homeTitle = document.getElementById('DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea');
  homeTitle.style.display = 'none';
  //Following code will hide the Exclamation with a circle next to it
  var homeToolTip = document.getElementById('ms-pageDescriptionImage');
  homeToolTip.style.display = 'none';
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideHomeTitle"); 
</script>
```

Comment: Dear @kauser this link to hide the home not to make it unclickable as Matt request

Comment: M.Qassas, I have updated my script which will now hide the Home title as per Matt request. Thanks